# Unable to update dynamic JSON element in called feature

Tags: karate

I am trying to create a shared utility feature which will edit a named element in a JSON structure.
In my main scenario outline, I can read and set the field using the `field_name` variable:

```
Feature: Main Feature

  Background: Setup
    * json req_body = {"event_id": "0123456789", "name": "my name"}

  Scenario Outline:
    * print "Value of field: ", req_body.<field_name>
    * set req_body.<field_name> = "New Value from main"
    * print "Value of field: ", req_body.<field_name>
    * karate.call(read('call_test.feature'))

    Examples:
      | field_name    |
      | event_id      |
      | name          |
```

```
Feature: call_test.feature

  Scenario:
    * print "req_body: ", req_body     # Gives the correct values
    * print "field: ", field_name
    * print req_body['#(field_name)']  # Doesn't work
    * def current_field = "req_body." + field_name
    * print "field contents (via get): ", karate.get(current_field)
```

In the called feature I was able to read the field by constructing a string of the JSON structure name and the field name connected by a dot, then passing that to `karate.get`. However, I am unable to set the named field in the called feature.

What am I missing?  What's the correct way to do this?